# how to convert GUID INTO int in sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have mentioned below table same I need to convert the [uniqueidentifier] to int values in entire database corresponding related tables as well. what is the best approach to implement this into production without impact ?

```
CREATE TABLE [usp].[Test]( [AccountId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Account_AccountId] DEFAULT (newsequentialid()), [AccountName] nvarchar NOT NULL, [AccountDescription] nvarchar NULL, [AccountStatusId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, [AccountTypeId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, [GeoLocation] varchar NULL, [ContactInfoId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL, [ParentId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL, [Encoding] varchar NOT NULL, [IsDeleted] [bit] NULL DEFAULT ((0)), [AccountHeirarchy] nvarchar NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_Account] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [AccountId] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

values examples below.

```
AccountId AccountName AccountDescription AccountStatusId AccountTypeId GeoLocation ContactInfoId ParentId Encoding IsDeleted AccountHeirarchy HID

A70D7DCE-4F1F-E211-AAA2-0050568F021A SysAccount Administrator Account A0000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 A70D7DCE-4F1F-E211-AAA2-0050568F021B NULL NULL NULL 1 0 NULL
```

Comment: uniqueidentifier is 16 bytes. A int is only 4. This isn't going to work. Is there any specific requirement to do such things?

Comment: provide examples in form of DML,which can be run..

Comment: For starters, you don't introduce this in production, you do this repeatedly in a test environment. The impact is going to be massive as it sounds like you are trying to change from using guids as primary keys to an int (possibly identity) as the primary key. This requires changing probably every single table in your database, it probably requires changing mountains of code, it will have a major impact on database size and fragmentation. In short, this type of change is a topic that is way bigger than an online forum. You should probably hire a consultant for this project.

Answer (score 1):

The sooner you get away from having guids on a clustered index the better. I'm assuming your problem is all the foreign keys that will need to change.

I'd explore the possibility of introducing the integer columns to the database in parallel, creating equivalent relationships and phasing out guids. If it's slow going I'd turn the guid into non clustered index and use integer for clustered index.
This sounds like a massive project. Good luck.

Answer (score -2):

you can use a C# script to convert varchar to int the method name is BitConverter.ToUInt32